# IN clause in select query with a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I join multiple tables. I would like to filter the results based on the status codes and I also want to get the records that were most recently created. Is the below SQL correct? Meaning - can I use IN clause for the statuscodes, or should it be three different queries, one for each status?

```
SELECT
         A.DetailID
       , H.PersonID
       , A.RateAmount
       , A.Code
       , A.TypeCode
FROM
         CMPN.Detail       A
       , CMPN.DetailStatus B
       , CMPN.Header       H
WHERE
         H.PayGroup IN ('A Pay Group','B Pay Group','C Pay Group')
         AND A.EndDate = '2020-02-10 06:00:00.0000000 +00:00'
         AND A.LastUpdateTimestamp      <= '2020-02-24 06:00:00.0000000 +00:00'
         AND A.DetailID = B.DetailID
         AND H.HeaderId = A.HeaderId
         AND **B.DetailStatusCode IN ('Approved','Completed','Pending')**
         AND B.CreateTimestamp =
         (
                SELECT
                       MAX(C.CreateTimestamp)
                FROM
                       CMPN.DetailStatus C
                WHERE
                       A.DetailID = C.DetailID AND **C.DetailStatusCode IN ('Approved','Completed','Pending'**)
         )
ORDER BY
         H.PersonID
       , A.Code
       , A.TypeCode
```

Comment: Does it give you the right results?

Comment: Your query does not use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  So, although it might compile to code that does what you want, I would not call the query itself "correct".

Comment: The only way to know if it's correct is to run it against known data. I can tell you it would be a hard fail in any shop where I've worked, simply because of the old obsolete join syntax.

Comment: Seconding the two comments above me; standard explicit JOIN syntax would make it fairly obvious you have no condition for joining CMPN.Header to either of the other two tables (and CROSS or INNER/LEFT JOIN would make it obvious whether that lack of condition was intentional).

Comment: Also: there's no meaningful join condition for the `Header` table. _Modern JOIN syntax would have made this error obvious!_ And, the `DetailStatus` table serves no purpose in this query so far.

Comment: Finally, the question is not clear. Do you want each `Detail` record to match up to three `DetailStatusRecords`, one each for the most recent `Approved`, `Completed`, and `Pending` statuses, or do you only want to match the single one record among those statuses which is most recent?

Comment: This is 2020, so you should learn to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not perfectly clear what you're after (see my comments on the question). But my best guess is you can do this with an `APPLY`:

```sql
SELECT d.DetailID, h.PersonID, d.RateAmount, d.Code, d.TypeCode
    , s.DetailStatusCode AS [Status], s.CreateTimeStamp As [StatusDate]
FROM CMPN.Detail d
CROSS APPLY ( -- change this to OUTER APPLY if you need it to behave more like a LEFT JOIN
    SELECT TOP 1 DetailSatusCode, CreateTimeStamp 
    FROM CMPN.DetailStatus ds 
    WHERE ds.DetailID = d.DetailID
        AND ds.DetailStatusCode IN ('Approved','Completed','Pending')
    ORDER BY ds.CreateTimeStamp DESC
) s
INNER JOIN CMPN.Header h ON h.HeaderID = d.HeaderID 
    AND h.PayGroup IN ('A Pay Group','B Pay Group','C Pay Group')
WHERE  d.EndDate = '2020-02-10 06:00:00.0000000 +00:00'
    AND d.LastUpdateTimestamp <= '2020-02-24 06:00:00.0000000 +00:00'
ORDER BY h.PersonID, d.Code, d.TypeCode
```

`APPLY` is like a correlated subquery/derived table in the `SELECT` clause, but it can be faster when you might have needed to use multiple subqueries against the same table. This allows us to only visit that table once to get both the `DetailStatusCode` and `CreateTimeStamp` columns. In Oracle and Postgresql this is called a `LATERAL JOIN`. These APPLY/Lateral join operations do not mix well with the old obsolete "A,B" join syntax, and is just one of *many* reasons not to use that old syntax.

Often the `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function can also be used for even better performance, with a condition where the row number equals 1.

Note there was initially no meaningful JOIN condition for the `Header` table. The explicit `JOIN` syntax helps make this kind of error more obvious. I also had to infer what fields you needed from `DetailStatus`. As it was, the table served no purpose in the original query.

Comment: Updated with the JOIN condition added to the question.